# Image with js encodeURI does not show in email

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, email

I am sending emails from my website. The email is html and contains an image.
It looks like the with encoded uris does not show in outlook, gmail etc.

This one does not show:
Path: [Example](http://www.example.com/fileshare/filarkivroot/Bilder/Rett%20til%20%C3%A5%20lese/Lydkort_bilder/15_Murakami_2_kort.jpg)

EmailSource(outlook):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
Test6<br><br><br><br>
<img alt="" src="http://www.example.com/fileshare/filarkivroot/Bilder/Rett%20til%20%C3%A5%20lese/Lydkort_bilder/15_Murakami_2_kort.jpg"> 
<br><br><br><br>
```

This one does show in the email:

Path:
`http://www.rettilaalese.no/fileshare/filarkivroot/shop/Produktgruppe/medium.jpg`

Email source(outlook):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
Test5<br><br><br><br>
<img alt="" src="http://example.com/fileshare/filarkivroot/shop/Produktgruppe/medium.jpg">
<br><br><br><br>Hilsen Espen
```

The images exists and is showing in browser when using correct url(not example.com)

Comment: Most modern email clients will block images until you allow them. This is because images can be used to determine if the email address is "live"; perfect for spammers. Are you getting any "images were blocked" warnings?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that, but that is not the problem. They won't show even if i choose "show images"